# <If> statement breaks Rewrite* rules

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using standard wordpress htaccess rules with Apache/2.4.34. If I add `<If>` statement it brakes rewrites.

```
# DEBUG is set to TRUE
<If "-T env('DEBUG')">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</If>
```

All pages except `/` returns: Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

```
blog.local 172.20.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2018:17:07:58 +0000] "GET /2018/09/19/popular/ HTTP/1.1" 400 226 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202467 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/web/2018 -> /var/www/html/web/2018/09/19/popular/
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202511 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri '/var/www/html/web/2018/09/19/popular/'
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202529 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/web/2018 -> /var/www/html/web/2018/09/19/popular/
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202543 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] applying pattern '^wp-admin$' to uri '/var/www/html/web/2018/09/19/popular/'
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202557 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/web/2018 -> /var/www/html/web/2018/09/19/popular/
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202570 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] applying pattern '^' to uri '/var/www/html/web/2018/09/19/popular/'
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202619 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/web/2018' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202638 2018] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/web/2018' pattern='-d' => not-matched
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202653 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/web/2018 -> /var/www/html/web/2018/09/19/popular/
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202666 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] applying pattern '.' to uri '/var/www/html/web/2018/09/19/popular/'
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202681 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] rewrite '/var/www/html/web/2018/09/19/popular/' -> 'index.php'
[Sun Sep 30 17:07:58.202693 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 7:tid 140686203255528] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 172.20.0.1:56856] 172.20.0.1 - - [blog.local/sid#55cd2e1aec50][rid#55cd2e246a80/initial] [perdir *If/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> *If/index.php
```

The last message is completely strange: `add per-dir prefix: index.php -> *If/index.php`

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar case with these `htaccess`rules:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/resources/data/character/[0-9]{1,10}/(avatar|refsheet)\.png$#">
    # ... Other stuff here ...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ resources/generic/default-refsheet.png
</If>
```

In such conditions, the request is rewritten to the *relative*  path `resources/generic/default-refsheet.png` when originally requested file does not exist (and when it matches the regex in the `<If>`), leading to the dumb `*If/` prefix being added.

It seems the directory prefix `*If/` used by Apache is a pleaceholder, as the content of `<If>` is always applied first, before the actual directory prefix could be computed.

In such case, I found no way to keep the rewritten URL relative, so I used an "absolute" (absolute is in quotes because it's actually still relative to the `DocumentRoot` of the virtual host, but not relative to the where `htaccess` is). Hence changing it the rule to `/resources/generic/default-refsheet.png` (note the `/` at first place):

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/resources/data/character/[0-9]{1,10}/(avatar|refsheet)\.png$#">
    # ...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /resources/generic/default-refsheet.png
</If>
```

In such case, the rewritten URL is not prefixed with the dumb `*If/` dir prefix.

So for your issue, I would try puttin a `/` (or a `/path/to/wordpress/from/document_root/`) in front of every rewritten rule:

```
# DEBUG is set to TRUE
<If "-T env('DEBUG')">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ /wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</If>
```

Still, I'm not 100% sure about whether it will work, nor about why it would work (hence the original bounty I placed)...

Answer (score 0):

You can change If statement to

```
<If "env('DEBUG') == true">
```